# Merging packages in UML 2 packages diagram

Tags: uml

How do merging packages on uml packages diagrams exactly work? I couldn't find any straightforward explanation neither in books nor in the internet.

I mean, let's say that package A merges package B. What would be the result? Package A having all its elements + the elements from package B?

What if there are two classes with the same name though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your example, the result of the merge would be new classes in package A. Package B is not affected.

For each class "Class" in B, we have the following procedure depending if the class with the same name exists in A:

- class "Class" does not exist in A. A new class "Class" is created in A, as derived from the class "Class" in B. So, a simple generalization is done.
- class "Class" already exists in A. Then, the existing class "Class" (from A) is extended by the features from the class "Class" in B, including methods, attributes and associations. The new class "Class" is therefore obtained by deriving the class "Class" from A from class "Class" in B.

Answer (score 0):

In order to respect the constraints while merging, the packages name of the merged classes will be changed for instance `package A;` then all the attributes and methods will also migrate to the class which has the same signature.